# How to build database logic?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have got a form with 3 input fields (date, time, telephone) and I need to build a database where I can select date and time from drop down menu (two separate tables where one has got date values another one has got time values).

Both of these date and time tables have another column with value 0 or 1. If this value is 0 you can select that time, but if the value is 1 it can't: e.g. I select the date and it shows me available times, so then I can add a telephone number and submit all values to another table (date, time, telephone I guess) - but if the time is already taken it can't be selected.

If all time slots are selected already you can't select that date because the date value changes from 0 to 1.

It's my first database project so I don't really understand things in database architecture yet. I don't need the code I'll figure it out, I just need to see how the database looks with all the tables, primary keys etc.

Comment: Which bit of this is the problem exactly? Reading your description, you seem to have come up with the table design already. Or are you really asking how to write the business logic to validate the date and time selections? That would normally be done in your application primarily, rather than the database (albeit with the help of a couple of queries to check the existing data, of course).

Comment: Don't have the 0/1 columns; dynamically figure out the value from the rows in the table.